# What values are safe to use to initialize class definition's static and const members?

Tags: actionscript-3

Phrased differently, this question could read, **"What is the order of compile-time variable declarations and definitions?"**

I can't recall specific examples at the moment, but I know I've run into trouble when initializing const and static values in my class definitions due to the declaration of those values occurring out of order.

I know I can instantiate objects when declaring static const members, like so:

```
public class ConstsWithNewObjects {
    public static const DEFINED_NOW_2:Object = {something:"Defined!"};
    public static const DEFINED_NOW_3:Object = new CustomObject("Defined!");
}
```

But, if I'm accessing one of those members from another static or const value, I imagine race conditions arising, like so:

```
public class ConstsWithOtherConsts {
    public static const DEFINED_NOW_1:Object = DEFINED_NOW_3; // Does this exist, yet?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActoinScript Hero Jack Dunstan has covered this exact topic in great detail on his blog: [Class Bootup Part 2](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1038).

Regardless of Jack's findings; I would recommend, for the sanity of your readers; that you keep your static initialiser code as clean, and simple as possible - don't forget that static fields can call static methods; you can also make use of a [static Class initialiser method](http://life.neophi.com/danielr/2006/12/static_initializers_in_as3_1.html) as well.